# Filter for many columns with dynamic data

Tags: filter, parameters, tableau-desktop

I need a help.
I am using Tableau for visualisation. Data in my DataBase are structured by unique keys (+1k rows). I need to filtered value from rows by 2 and more columns (2columns+_filter). And this filtered data must be react to other Filters ("category") on My_Dashboard.

What I used:
Combination from `Parameter` and `Calculation Field`.
`Parameter` - includes data from 2 and more columns (I added it manualy).
`Calculation Field` - based on `Contains(Column1, Parameter) OR...` to the last column.
But it doesnot work, because `Parameter` included data what could be excluded by Filters on  My_Dashboard.

Is it possible make a "dynamic filter" what will be select data (rows what inludes "value_1" from range column_1-column_3 after applying  Filter - "category1" only.

For example - Input:

| rows | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row_key_1 | value_1 |  | value_5 | category_1 |
| row_key_2 |  | value5 | value_1 | category_2 |
| row_key_3 | value_5 |  |  | category_1 |

Output:

| rows | column_1 | column_4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row_key_1 | value_1 | category_1 |

Mayth be it possible with SQL addon/plugin, or something other.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understood how can realise what I want. If you have the same task,  what you need:

- add two DataBase (or sheets from excel, etc.) and connect them with unique key "first_db_key = second_db_key";
- first DataBase sctuctured by horizontal, 1 row with unique key and a lot of columns with value;
- second DataBase sctuctured by our target column (included all possible values waht we need) and ofcourse rows with "unique key" from "first DataBase" could be repeated (2 or more).
- on you Sheet need to add filter based on "target column" from "second DataBase", after that, add filter to the "Context" and choose "All using this data source" option on "Apply to Worksheets" in context menu (rigth button click on the filter)
- on you Dashboard select to show filter what you added before, and in filter menu choose "All Values in Context" option.
  Finaly you are get result what you want.